# Plot cost function for Random Forest against sample size in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I would like to aestimate the cost function of a random forest model fed by several subsets of my training/test data. The subsets are increasing in size. Comparing the cost against the training and then test sample size I would like to explore the possibility of having an underfit in my data (which I suspect).

The question is: how can I obtain the cost of one or more RF executions and plot it in R?

Comment: Completely confused!

Comment: Ok, let me refactor the question to be much more linear: forget about cost function, I'd like to know if there's a way to understand 1. if i need more training samples or features 2. if my hypothesis suffers of underfit 3. if my hypothesis suffers of overfit

Comment: I hope have understood what you mean. If not, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. if i need more training samples or features: See the next part.
2. if my hypothesis suffers of underfit/overfit? See this: 
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Overfitting_svg.svg (from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)

If you are before the exclamation sign: underfit
If you are after the exclamation sign: overfit

Comment: Many tnx! That's really a nice and intuite graph! Do you know how to plot this in R (i use the random forest package with caret)?

Comment: I don't. But it is not hard. Just evaluate the performance of your system both on train and test data, at each iteration.

Comment: I will :) tnx allot